# Udev rule for turning on an external monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, udev

I have a  udev rule to switch some XFCE panels when an external monitor is added.

```
ACTION=="change", KERNEL=="card0", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl start hot_plug.service"
```

This starts the service `hot_plug.service`, which in turn runs a script to configure the panels. However my external monitor can be turned on/off, and this will not result in running the service. Is it possible to make udev listen to turning on/off of the external monitor?

Comment: To trigger systemd on action 'change' you need to use SYSTEMD_READY=1 can look something like `TAG+="systemd",ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="1", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="some.service"`

Comment: [systemd.device](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html)